# How to sort results in MySQL right join?

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, group-by

I am trying to get monthly data of whole year using MySQL using below two tables,

1. loan
2. month

**loan**

```
` +--------+--------+-------+----------+
| idloan | amount | tot   | interest |
+--------+--------+-------+----------+
|      3 |  10000 | 15000 |       50 |
|      4 |   5000 |  6000 |       10 |
|      5 |  20000 | 30000 |       10 |
|      6 |  30000 |  3000 |       10 |
|      7 |  15000 | 16500 |       10 |
+--------+--------+-------+----------+ `
```

**month**

```
`+---------+-------+
| idmonth | month |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | 1     |
|       2 | 2     |
|       3 | 3     |
|       4 | 4     |
|       5 | 5     |
|       6 | 6     |
|       7 | 7     |
|       8 | 8     |
|       9 | 9     |
|      10 | 10    |
|      11 | 11    |
|      12 | 12    |
+---------+-------+ `
```

I used this query to get, count of idloan, sum of amount and sum of total of each month,

```
` SELECT
  m.month,
  COUNT(l.idloan)AS m_count,
  COALESCE(SUM(l.amount),0)AS amount,
  COALESCE(SUM(l.total),0)AS total
  FROM loan l RIGHT JOIN month m using(month)
GROUP BY m.month `
```

and the output is

```
` +-------+---------+--------+-------+
| month | m_count | amount | total |
+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| 1     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 10    |       1 |  15000 | 16500 |
| 11    |       1 |  30000 |  3000 |
| 12    |       3 |  35000 | 51000 |
| 2     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 3     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 4     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 5     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 6     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 7     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 8     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 9     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
+-------+---------+--------+-------+ `
```

My question is how can I sort this to get output like this

```
` +-------+---------+--------+-------+
| month | m_count | amount | total |
+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| 1     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 2     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 3     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 4     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 5     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 6     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 7     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 8     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 9     |       0 |      0 |     0 |
| 10    |       1 |  15000 | 16500 |
| 11    |       1 |  30000 |  3000 |
| 12    |       3 |  35000 | 51000 |
+-------+---------+--------+-------+ `
```

Comment: Store month as an integer or, better still, using a date data type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just need an order by clause. So your query should be

```
 SELECT
  m.month,
  COUNT(l.idloan)AS m_count,
  COALESCE(SUM(l.amount),0)AS amount,
  COALESCE(SUM(l.total),0)AS total
  FROM loan l RIGHT JOIN month m using(month)
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER BY CONVERT(m.month,UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should change the data type of **month** column of **month table** to INT.

Anyways you could still cast/convert the string to integer in your order by clause.

Something like below

```
SELECT m.month, 
COUNT(l.idloan)AS m_count,
COALESCE(SUM(l.amount),0)AS amount, 
COALESCE(SUM(l.total),0)AS total FROM loan l 
RIGHT JOIN month m using(month) GROUP BY m.month 
ORDER BY CONVERT(m.month,UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Would recommend you to change the data type rather than using **CONVERT** in your order by clause.